# ArrayList Object storing multiple values

Tags: java

```
List<Dictionary> DictionaryList= new ArrayList<Dictionary>();
```

I created ArrayList object, i need to store multiple name with keys and want to display name along with keys. How can i do it. Please help me

Comment: why don't you just use a map to store key-value pairs??.. why an arrayList of maps/dictionaries?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html ?

Comment: You just need to use the right data structure ;)

Comment: choosing the right data structure is half the job in programming

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [`Map<K,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead.

Considering you need a `String` to `String` mapping, a `Map` can be instantiated as :

```
Map<String, String> mapOfNames = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Insertions are as easy as :

```
mapOfNames.put(key, name);
```

And retrievals :

```
String name = mapOfNames.get(key);
```

Now considering that there might be multiple values associated with the same key, you will have to modify the `Map` to a `HashMap<String, List<String>>`. That is, each `key` will correspond to a `list of values`.

So the definition will then be of the form :

```
Map<String, List<String>> mapOfNames = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

Insertion :

```
mapOfNames.get(key).add(name);
```

Retrieval :

```
List<String> retrievedNamesForKey = mapOfNames.get(key);
```

More about `HashMaps` can be found here : [HashMap (Java Platform SE 7 )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: @Sathesh : Yes, the key is unique. Inserting multiple values with the same key will over-write the previously inserted one.

Comment: how to prevent value from that over-writing

Comment: @Sathesh : I've edited the answer to make sure that corresponding to each key, you can maintain a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I think the object you are looking for is a map

consider the [java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) HashMap

```
HashMap<String,Value> map = new HashMap<String,Value>();
```

- Insert an object for Value in your implementation.

Add a key value pair... The key is whatever you are using for the value

```
map.put("name1",23);
```

Now lets access one of those entries

```
map.get("name1"); // returns 23
```

Using parameterized classes is simple once you get the hang of it. [See the Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

- Make sure you use objects to specify the  pairs
- So with this example use Integer() for numbers not int

Comment: What do you mean with "regular map" - do you refer to TreeMap? Because Map is just an interface.